# MongoError: Expression $in takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

- below is my query:
         while executing below query getting mongoerror : Expression $in takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.
     i am using $in Comparison operator

  ```
  {
      "$expr": {
          "$not": {
              "$eq":{
                  "$and": [
                      {
                          "PrName": {
                              "$in": [
                                  "pname"
                              ]
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          "AccountId": {
                              "$in": [
                                  "34562",                      
                                  "88765",
                                  "87654",
                                  "12345"
                              ]
                          }
                      }
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 13):

When you use `$expr`, the [operator expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#operator-expressions) syntax changes a little:

```
{ $in: [ <expression>, <array expression> ] }
```

---

```
{
  "$expr": {
    "$not": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "$in": [
            "$PrName",
            [
              "pname"
            ]
          ]
        },
        {
          "$in": [
            "$AccountId",
            [
              "34562",
              "88765",
              "87654",
              "12345"
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had used `aggregate` function and multiple `$lookup` and `pipeline`.

Example: At first was getting a product with slug, all product have `keywords[]`.
I had to get related products that have at least one matching keywords.

My related_products looked like:

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "Products",
    let: {
      // ...
      productKeywords: { $arrayElemAt: ["$product.keywords", 0] }
    },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
        $expr: {
          $and: [
            // ...
            { $ne: ["$slug", slug] },
              { $or: [
                // ... more conditions like same category, etc.
                { keywords: { $in: "$$productKeywords" } }
              ] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  as: "related_products"
},
```

I was getting this error and I knew `$in` in `$expr` works differently. When I changed it to `{ $in: ["$keywords", "$$productKeywords"] }`, it was not giving any product by matching keywords though there were many products.
After searching all online, I can't find the solution.

Finally after many hours of searching and thinking, something new idea came on my mind. If I perform intersection on keywords with productKeywords and if the result keyword size is one or larger, it means there is matching keyword . If the keywords match, it is the related product.
I just replaced `$in` with below line.

```
{ $gt: [{ $size: { $setIntersection: ["$keywords", "$$productKeywords"] } }, 0] }
```

This is working on my case as I have expected.