# MongoError: Expression $in takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in. '{ $in: [ <expression>, <array expression> ] }' not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to run this below query. `update.keywords` and `update.genre` are array of strings. I'm using MongoDB v4.4.0

```
let similar = await VideoSchema.find(
        { _id: { $ne: id } },
        {
          $or: [
            { influencerId: update.influencerId },
            { category: update.category },
            { keywords: { $in: [...update.keywords] } },
            { genre: { $in: [...update.genre] } },
          ],
        }
      );
```

[MongoError: Expression $in takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62407638/mongoerror-expression-in-takes-exactly-2-arguments-1-were-passed-in)
I referred to this answer but I'm not using `'$expr'` in my query. How can I find all the similar videos using this query.
and if I try doing using `{ $in: [ <expression>, <array expression> ] }` it gives me another error i.e. `MongoError: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you have curly braces around `or`.

Syntax for find is `db.coll.find(findCondition}, {projection})`

If you want to perform `and`, you can pass `id` query and `or` query to it.

```
VideoSchema.find(
        { $and: [
          {_id: { $ne: id }}, 
          {$or: [
            { influencerId: update.influencerId },
            { category: update.category },
            { keywords: { $in: [...update.keywords] } },
            { genre: { $in: [...update.genre] } },
          ] }
        ]} 
      );
```

Otherwise add it inside the part of find condition. It is OR condition.

```
VideoSchema.find(
        { _id: { $ne: id }, 
          $or: [
            { influencerId: update.influencerId },
            { category: update.category },
            { keywords: { $in: [...update.keywords] } },
            { genre: { $in: [...update.genre] } },
          ]
        }
      );
```

Comment: thanks it solved my issue. I didn't notice I was writing it wrong :D